# how to define template member function with unnamed typename?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I have a problem in defining template member function with unnamed typename.

code is down below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class A
{};

class B : public A
{};

class C
{
  public:
  template <typename T,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<A, T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
    void do_stuff(T& t);
};

template <typename T>
void C::do_stuff(T& t)
{
}

int main(){  
  B b;
  C c;
  c.do_stuff<B>(b);
}
```

when compile this

```
/home/insights/insights.cpp:19:9: error: out-of-line definition of 'do_stuff' does not match any declaration in 'C'
void C::do_stuff(T& t)
        ^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

how to achieve that?

Comment: `template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<A, T>::value, T>::type*> void C::do_stuff(T& t) {}`.

Comment: The name is irrelevant. You only need to give the type and if you want you can invent any name anyway.

Comment: Just like `void foo(int x,int)` and `void foo(int x)` are two different functions, your `template <typename T> void C::do_stuff(T& t)` is not the same as the template you declare. Just because the argument has no name does not imply you could drop it